# How can I add custom scalars to the neo4j graphql library for my apollo server?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo-server, neo4j-graphql-js

Is there a way to add custom scalars with neo4j graphql library.
I am using neo4j 4.4 with apollo server.

I want to write a query for my graphql API that returns the result the following cypher query from my database :

```
match (p:PATENT {app_num : "17037200"})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(p, {
    relationshipFilter: "IS_PARENT_OF"
})
YIELD node
with distinct node as p
optional match (parent:PATENT)-[:IS_PARENT_OF]->(p)
with distinct parent as unique_parent ,p
with collect(unique_parent.app_num) as parents, p
optional match (p)-[:IS_PARENT_OF]->(child:PATENT)
with distinct child as unique_child ,p, parents
with collect(unique_child.app_num) as children, p.app_num as application, parents
return application, parents, children
```

This returns a json type structure and I want this custom query to be served at my apollo API as a data point.

What are my options ?

I also want to mention that if we normally make a scalar like we do in apollo then we loose the magic of neo4j graphql library which generates a CRUD API for us.

Is there a way in which we can do both i.e create a scalar and also let the neo4j graphql library do the magic.

I was not able to find any thing related to in the docs.

Comment: Can you show the code where you attempt to define a custom scalar? You can also refer to the implementation of the [JSON](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars/blob/master/src/scalars/json/JSON.ts) custom scalar from the graphql-scalars package.